# Conda-forge spaCy install fails - Error: WinError 87 - the parameter is incorrect

Tags: windows-10, anaconda, spacy

I'm trying to install spaCy in a conda environment (Anaconda 2019.03 - latest release) on Windows 10 using the command "conda install -c conda-forge spacy" recommended on the spaCy website. However I'm receiving OS Error 22 / WinError 87(the parameter is incorrect) when conda tries to install dependencies.

I've also tried installing spaCy using pip, but I run into similar difficulties. I get the same WinError 87 error - "the parameter is incorrect".

The full output from the conda attempt is:

```
(fever) C:\Users\Shmuli>conda install -v -c  conda-forge spacy

.....

===> LINKING PACKAGE: conda-forge::attrs-19.1.0-py_0 <===
  prefix=C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\envs\fever
  source=C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\pkgs\attrs-19.1.0-py_0


===> REVERSING PACKAGE LINK: conda-forge::attrs-19.1.0-py_0 <===
  prefix=C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\envs\fever


failed
An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::attrs-19.1.0-py_0'.
OSError(22, 'The parameter is incorrect', None, 87, None)
Attempting to roll back.


Rolling back transaction: ...working... ===> REVERSING PACKAGE LINK: conda-forge::asn1crypto-0.24.0-py37_1003 <===
  prefix=C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\envs\fever


===> REVERSING PACKAGE LINK: conda-forge::liblapack-3.8.0-10_mkl <===
  prefix=C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\envs\fever


===> REVERSING PACKAGE LINK: conda-forge::libcblas-3.8.0-10_mkl <===
  prefix=C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\envs\fever


===> REVERSING PACKAGE LINK: conda-forge::openssl-1.1.1b-hfa6e2cd_2 <===
  prefix=C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\envs\fever


===> REVERSING PACKAGE LINK: conda-forge::libblas-3.8.0-10_mkl <===
  prefix=C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\envs\fever


===> REVERSING PACKAGE LINK: defaults::mkl-2019.3-203 <===
  prefix=C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\envs\fever


rm_rf failed for C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\envs\fever\Library\bin\mkl_vml_avx2.dll

rm_rf failed for C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\envs\fever\Library\bin\mkl_rt.dll

rm_rf failed for C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\envs\fever\Library\bin\mkl_intel_thread.dll

rm_rf failed for C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\envs\fever\Library\bin\mkl_core.dll

rm_rf failed for C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\envs\fever\Library\bin\mkl_avx2.dll

===> REVERSING PACKAGE LINK: defaults::intel-openmp-2019.3-203 <===
  prefix=C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\envs\fever


rm_rf failed for C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\envs\fever\Library\bin\libiomp5md.dll

===> REVERSING PACKAGE LINK: conda-forge::ca-certificates-2019.3.9-hecc5488_0 <===
  prefix=C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\envs\fever


===> REVERSING PACKAGE UNLINK: defaults::ca-certificates-2019.1.23-0 <===
  prefix=C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\envs\fever


===> REVERSING PACKAGE UNLINK: defaults::openssl-1.1.1b-he774522_1 <===
  prefix=C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\envs\fever


===> REVERSING PACKAGE UNLINK: defaults::certifi-2019.3.9-py37_0 <===
  prefix=C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\envs\fever


done
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\link.py", line 622, in _execute_actions
    action.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\path_actions.py", line 558, in execute
    self.target_prefix, self.transaction_context['target_python_version'])
  File "C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\disk\create.py", line 380, in compile_multiple_pyc
    stdout, stderr, rc = any_subprocess(command, prefix)
  File "C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\subprocess.py", line 45, in any_subprocess
    stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, env=env)
  File "C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\link.py", line 553, in _execute
    cls._execute_actions(pkg_idx_tracked, axngroup)
  File "C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\link.py", line 638, in _execute_actions
    reverse_excs,
conda.CondaMultiError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1003, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 82, in do_call
    exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
  File "C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_install.py", line 20, in execute
    install(args, parser, 'install')
  File "C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 275, in install
    handle_txn(unlink_link_transaction, prefix, args, newenv)
  File "C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 304, in handle_txn
    unlink_link_transaction.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\link.py", line 241, in execute
    self._execute(tuple(concat(interleave(itervalues(self.prefix_action_groups)))))
  File "C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\link.py", line 587, in _execute
    rollback_excs,
conda.CondaMultiError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

I tried just installing attrs using conda and received this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\link.py", line 622, in _execute_actions
    action.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\path_actions.py", line 558, in execute
    self.target_prefix, self.transaction_context['target_python_version'])
  File "C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\disk\create.py", line 380, in compile_multiple_pyc
    stdout, stderr, rc = any_subprocess(command, prefix)
  File "C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\subprocess.py", line 45, in any_subprocess
    stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, env=env)
  File "C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\link.py", line 553, in _execute
    cls._execute_actions(pkg_idx_tracked, axngroup)
  File "C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\link.py", line 638, in _execute_actions
    reverse_excs,
conda.CondaMultiError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1003, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 82, in do_call
    exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
  File "C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_install.py", line 20, in execute
    install(args, parser, 'install')
  File "C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 275, in install
    handle_txn(unlink_link_transaction, prefix, args, newenv)
  File "C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 304, in handle_txn
    unlink_link_transaction.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\link.py", line 241, in execute
    self._execute(tuple(concat(interleave(itervalues(self.prefix_action_groups)))))
  File "C:\Users\Shmuli\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\link.py", line 587, in _execute
    rollback_excs,
conda.CondaMultiError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why exactly the WinError 87 was thrown, but I managed to solve the issue by shutting off auto containment in Comodo. Instructions for how to do so can be found here: https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/617328967248066054/

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to update anaconda with dthis command:
conda update --all

But the update failed, an error occurred:
[WinError 87] Incorrect parameter update conda

I tried to uninstall and install again but the error still occurs, so in my case the problem was Comodo antivirus, I had to turn off auto containment in Comodo.