# EnvironmentError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect

Tags: python, pip

I attempted to execute:

```
python -m pip install tensorflow
```

from a Windows 10 command prompt that was being run as administrator.

I got the following error:

```
Collecting tensorflow
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/54/5f/e1b2d83b808f978f51b7ce109315154da3a3d4151aa59686002681f2e109/tensorflow-2.0.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting google-pasta>=0.1.6
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c3/fd/1e86bc4837cc9a3a5faf3db9b1854aa04ad35b5f381f9648fbe81a6f94e4/google_pasta-0.1.8-py3-none-any.whl (57kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 435kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: keras-preprocessing>=1.0.5 in c:\users\owner\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<2.0,>=1.16.0 in c:\users\owner\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.17.4)
Collecting wrapt>=1.11.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/23/84/323c2415280bc4fc880ac5050dddfb3c8062c2552b34c2e512eb4aa68f79/wrapt-1.11.2.tar.gz
    ERROR: Error [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect while executing command python setup.py egg_info
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

I tried this both from the PyCharm terminal (64-bit version) and from Python 3.7.4 (from the 64-bit build). Using the 64-bit version seemed important according to tensorflow.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution for this question gave me the inspiration: [Conda-forge spaCy install fails - Error: WinError 87 - the parameter is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56305542/conda-forge-spacy-install-fails-error-winerror-87-the-parameter-is-incorrec)

I went to COMODO Internet Security Premium and selected Autocontainment -> Disabled for 15 minutes. Then I re-ran the command

```
python -m pip install tensorflow
```

from that Windows 10 command prompt that was being run as administrator.

Comment: Thank you very much! was trying to pip install stb and never would have thought that disabling Comodo would have helped.

Comment: MAN I OWE YOU MY LIFE DUDE ! its been around 20 hours !!! THANK YOU !

Answer (score 3):

It also worked for me I disabled the comodo and ran "pip install pyttsx3 --user"

Comment: Can you share a little more context for your answer? What did you understand the problem to be, and how does your solution fix the problem?

Comment: My client machine has comodo installed. I disabled 'Auto-Containment' and the process went further.

Comment: Adding the --user param helps me install other packages.